# Find duplicates within each subset of data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have Doubt in Comparing two Columns.

[image]

Column **B** must have Unique Data's with in Column **A** Duplicates range (range highlighted different colours).

Column **A** have Duplicate Data's > That is need to set as range for compare column **B** (uneven qty)

Example:

- ***SET 1***

**19A19**  *-*

**19A19**  *N0025R0*

- ***SET 2***

**A057** *021-21----*

**A057** *021-22----*

=IF(A2=A:A,IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2),B2=B3,""),"")  Currently i tried this formula
(its only compare MAT column one by one)

I need Correct Result, as RED Highlights Anyone help me .

Comment: Hi @baskar,, your attached screen shot is quit confusing,, Neither column A nor B has Unique value,, and if you are expecting Unique than how do you think to compare Duplicates,, please [edit] your post and reload proper data,, also what is the formula you have tried in FORMULA column !!

Comment: @RajeshS updated now

Comment: ,, unfortunately not finding and noticeable updates ,,you have written "Column MAT must have Unique Data's ,,, but has DUPLICATES,,, and how could you compare MAT with PARTs ,,, since have different combinations,, how could compare 52 with any Part number ??

Comment: MAT column Need to compare that is our idea. Here PART A2,A3 duplicates , So Column B comparison Within B2,B3. Then we need to do the process for all below parts

Comment: Part column doesn't have A2,, A3,,, and MAT had only Numbers ??

Comment: Both Columns Have Combination of Numbes,text,symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rephrasing of the problem:**

Column A contains a list of categories.
Column B contains a list of sub-categories.
We need to detect and flag duplicate sub-categories within each category in A.

For example:

```
Fruit    Banana    Duplicate!
Fruit    Apple     
Fruit    Banana    Duplicate!
Veg      Tomato    
Veg      Potato    Duplicate!
Veg      Potato    Duplicate!
```

**Assumption:**

Data is sorted by category / column A.

**Solution:**

First define some names. Define the data in col A as *data1* and the data in col B as *data2*.

Then in C2:
=IF(COUNTIF(*grouprange*,B2)>1,"Duplicate","")

where *grouprange* is =INDEX(data2,MATCH(A2,data1,0)):INDEX(data2,MATCH(A2,data1,0)+COUNTIF(data1,A2)-1)

If you want to be fancy, actually define *grouprange* as a named range in Excel.
Put your cursor in C2, click Formulas > Define Name, and add the formula above to the "refers to" textbox. Now, *grouprange* is known as a dynamic named range (i.e. a named range that changes based on the location of the cell it is used in). It will return the whole subcategory range of the category currently selected. For instance, if subcategory was a number you could put in column c =SUM(grouprange).

Comment: To understand how grouprange is defined, here it is in abstract form (relative to C2) = INDEX(data2, *first occurrence of A2 in data1*):INDEX(data2, *first occurrence of A2 in data1* + *number of occurrences of A2 in data1* - 1)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(data1, A2, data2, B2)>1,"Duplicate","")
```

This is so much easier!

**Explanation**

Lets have a quick look at what is going on in this formula. First of all it helps to think of the size of the data (vector dimensions). data1 and data2 are column vectors of n x 1 each. A2 is a scalar (1 x 1) and when compared like this (data1 = A2) generates another n x 1 vector e.g. ( true ; true ; false ...).

COUNTIF(data1, A2) will basically count the number of true values in the comparison vector and generate a single scalar value (sum) equal to the number of occurrences of A2 in data1. COUNTIF**S** does the same, but for multiple sets of criteria. So count the number of true values in the combined comparison vector AND(data1 = A2, data2 = B).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Wow really simple